# Checking availability of DB2 database via db2cli

Tags: shell, db2

I try to check the availability of a DB2 Instance via the `db2cli`-utility, as follows

```
db2cli execsql -user USER -passwd PASSWD -connstring DATABASE:HOST:PORT
```

(with actual values for the uppercased text). I would expect this to connect to HOST:PORT, using the credentials USER and PASSWD, and to switch to database DATABASE.

As a result i get

```
SQLError: rc = 0 (SQL_SUCCESS) 
SQLGetDiagRec: SQLState     : 08001
      fNativeError : -1024
      szErrorMsg   : [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1024N  A database connection does not exist.      SQLSTATE=08003
      cbErrorMsg   : 82
```

**But: these values WORK, on the same machine**, if i use them as credentials in applications that connect to DB2, so i would expect that i get a connection with the given command.

**My Question is: am i using `db2cli` wrong?**

Comment: Did you have a chance to look in the manual? It explains how to correctly specify `db2cli` parameters. (Hint: you may want to choose the `validate` subcommand.)

Comment: i had, albeit i am a little confused by it. i expected to get a shell where i may type random sql on success. i'm looking into validate, thank you

Answer (score 2):

You are using wrong connection string as well as options. Check correct command syntax by running "**db2cli execsql -help**" command.

You can use -user and -passwd option with -dsn option only. If you are using connection string, then uid and pwd should be part of -connstring option value. Also, the syntax of connection string is wrong. It must be a pair of keyword and value separated by semicolon and enclosed by quotes like "key1=val1;key2=val2;key3=val3". The correct command that you should use is:

**db2cli execsql -connstring "DATABASE=dbname;HOSTNAME=hostname;PORT=portnumber;UID=userid;PWD=passwd"**

The output for me is as below:

```
$ db2cli execsql -connstring "database=bluemix;hostname=192.168.1.20;port=50000;uid=myuid;pwd=mydbpassword"
IBM DATABASE 2 Interactive CLI Sample Program
(C) COPYRIGHT International Business Machines Corp. 1993,1996 
All Rights Reserved
Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or
disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp.
> select 'bluemix' from sysibm.sysdummy1
select 'bluemix' from sysibm.sysdummy1
FetchAll:  Columns: 1
  1
  bluemix
FetchAll: 1 rows fetched.
> quit

$
```

To know the instance name, you should run db2level command.

```
$ db2level
DB21085I  This instance or install (instance name, where applicable: "bimaljha") uses
"64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL10054" with level identifier "0605010E".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v10.5.0.4", "s140813", "IP23623", and Fix Pack "4".
Product is installed at "/home/bimaljha/sqllib".
```

Comment: Is it possible to suppress copyright information and footer?

Answer (score 0):

you can try validate connect like below(it will make you sure if connection is successful)

db2cli validate -dsn sample -connect

db2cli.ini :

[sample]

hostname=host

pwd=password

port=portnumber

PROTOCOL=TCPIP

database=dbname

uid=username